# Exchange, Replace Expired Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-server

I have an expired five name certificate that I want to replace with a wild card cert. The wild card cert is currently handling SMTP. I want to add IMAP. Because it's a wild card cert I'm following the instructions to use

`Set-ImapSettings -X509CertificateName mail.mydomain.com`

and I get a response of

```
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'myServer\1' have been modified.
```

And the wild card cert does not have the IMAP service added.

How do I do this? Do I need to remove the old expired cert first?

This is on premise Exchange 2019

Answer (score 0):

Was able to finally get it working with no clear answer. I wish MS would fix the GUI to show when a wildcard is being used for POP and IMAP. For anyone that comes along after with the same issue, use the only SSL checking tools to see when your connection is secure and some combinations of using the command and a couple of service restarts got it working. It appeared as magic, but there is not magic. Sorry I can't off any better advice.